# writing to a given void* memory location in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that takes as one of its parameters "void* buffer". In this function, I need to write to that memory location. However, doing something like

```
*buffer = "Hello\0Hi\0";
```

doesn't work because I can't dereference a void* pointer. How do I put <strike>a string</strike> data into that memory location? Note that I need to copy data, not necessarily a string, as it may contain the null character.

**Updated** to reflect that strcpy is not enough

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you string "may contain the null character," then it isn't really a C string.

If you need to copy a certain number of bytes from one memory location to another, regardless of the contents, you can use `memcpy`.  You can get the size of the string literal using `sizeof` (this size includes the final, implicit null terminator).

Comment: I'd be careful advising the use of sizeof to determine the size of the string. Yes, 'sizeof("Hello")' will give you the right answer. But 'char* p = "Hello"; .. sizeof(p); ' will not.

Comment: @user434507:  While that's true, it's the only way for the OP to get the size of his "string" unless he defines some other way to identify the end of the "string."

Comment: I never said it was a string, just data. Thanks for the tip on memcpy :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the assignment operator to copy a string. You'll need to use something like strcat (which, by the way, is VERY unsafe).

You're probably looking for

```
strcpy( (char *) buffer, "Hello");
```

Or better still, use strncpy. You absolutely need to pass in the size of the buffer and make sure you don't overrun it, or else you have a HUGE security hole in your application, not to mention the source of countless hard-to-trace bugs.

Comment: You don't need to cast `void *` to another kind of pointer. This isn't C++.

Comment: `strncpy` is wrong for two reasons: (a) the data contains embedded nuls, so `mempcy` is appropriate and specifies a length already. (b) `strncpy` was not designed as a safe string copy function, and it shows, and you can implement a better one yourself if your implementation doesn't provide one and/or you're writing portable code. (Downvote removed, once I noticed you answered before the edit that put in the embedded nuls. And if I downvoted people just for thinking that `strncpy` is a suitable safe string copy function, I'd hit the daily cap...)

Comment: Steve, thanks for removing the downvote, I appreciate that. I wouldn't necessarily say strncpy is a safe alternative, but I wanted to make it clear that strcpy definitely is NOT the way to go, and there needs to be some proper bounds checking. Writing "strncpy" is faster than ranting on about that. Also - you're right that memcpy is right if you know the length (i.e. if it's a string literal), but I was more thinking about a general string assignment, i.e. assuming the function gets a const char * rather than string with a known length.